# How can we create dynamic type in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a master table which contains information of lookup tables, base tables, master tables, primary columns, base columns. Using that information I am creating dynamic SQL statements and execute those via `execute immediate`.

As there are many records in the transaction, I am using bulk collect. To collect records in bulk, I want to create dynamic types in Oracle at run-time based on the columns available in master.

Below is code structure:

```
create or replace procedure pro_name(code varchar2,retmsg out varchar2)as
rec_master scr_master_data%rowtype;
type fstcurtype is ref cursor;
  cur_fname fstcurtype;
  v_sql varchar2(5000);
  v_ran_sql varchar2(5000);

begin

SELECT *
  INTO rec_master
  FROM SCR_MASTER_DATA
  WHERE SCREMBLING_CODE = P_SCREMBLING_CODE
  AND ACTIVE            ='Y';

 v_sql := 'select distinct '||rec_master.primary _columns||','||rec_master.base_columns||' from '||rec_master.base_tables;

  v_ran_sql:= 'select '||rec_master.LOOKUP_COLUMNS||' from (select /*+ parallel('||rec_master.LOOKUP_TABLES||',16) */ '||rec_master.LOOKUP_COLUMNS
               ||' from '||rec_master.LOOKUP_TABLES ||' order by dbms_random.value ) where rownum = 1';

 OPEN CUR_FNAME for v_sql;
 LOOP
    FETCH CUR_FNAME BULK COLLECT INTO rec_fname LIMIT NVL(rec_master.ROWS_TO_COMMIT,10000) ;
.
.
.
.
exception
when others then
.
.
end;
```

i want to create a type based on variable `v_sql`. Whatever columns mentioned in that statement should be used for the type.

I tried to add below code after `v_ran_sql` as well but it was a waste of effort.

```
execute immediate 'type ty_name is record(row_id varchar2(500),fst_name varchar2(500),acc_number varchar2(500))';
execute immediate 'rec_fname ty_name';
```

in which `row_id`, `fst_name`, `acc_number` column name will come from the master table.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You seem to be trying to use PL/SQL type and variable declaration statements inside your execute immediate call, which is a SQL context. You could potentially create a schema-level type, but creating objects at runtime isn't usually a good idea, every reference to that would also have to be dynamic, and you couldn't use it for the bulk-collect clause as it wouldn't exist at compile time. Do you really need the collection - what are you doing with the data?

Comment: Possible answer could be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973313/how-to-define-types-dynamically-in-plsql

Comment: What do you plan to make with your `rec_fname` data? Usually I would expect you can run this in one single (dynamic) SQL statement and you don't have to make any loop.

Comment: hi, thanks for response , actually i want to make generic procedure which would run based on master configuration.

Comment: master configuration would be define by user with its respective table which can be very DB to DB. based on that base table data will be scramble and store to different table which will use to manipulate data in base table afterwards.

Comment: master table design:
CREATE TABLE "SCR_MASTER_DATA"
   ( "SCREMBLING_CODE" VARCHAR2(10),
 "DESCRIPTIONS" VARCHAR2(100), 
 "BASE_TABLES" VARCHAR2(100),  "PRIMARY_COLUMN" VARCHAR2(100),
 "BASE_COLUMNS" VARCHAR2(100),change in scrambling
 "LOOKUP_TABLES" VARCHAR2(100),
 "LOOKUP_COLUMNS" VARCHAR2(100), 
 "ROWS_TO_COMMIT" NUMBER, 
 "ACTIVE" CHAR(1), 
 "CHILD_RECORD_YN" CHAR(1), 
 "PROCESS_STATUS" VARCHAR2(20), 
 "PREPARED_SCR_TABLE" VARCHAR2(100), 
 "PREPARED_SCR_COLUMNS" VARCHAR2(100)
   ) ;

Comment: want to make dynamic rec_fname which will be based on data set in to master table, if master having 2 columns then records should be with 2 columns as mentioned , if there is 3 columns define then it would be 3 columns .. like this.. but not finding any think supporting my logic.. if you could direct me any other way around then it would be grateful.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49381999/edit) to add all that information. You still haven't said what you will do with the type or the data you bulk collect or how you plan to refer to the fields in `rec_fname`  - which would have to be dynamic too, probably all in a single dynamic PlL/SQL block. Which sounds like a horrible solution, but without knowing what you are really trying to do (your actual task, not what your current idea), who knows...